# Map column values by ID based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID 1', 'ID 1', 'ID 1', 'ID 2', 'ID 2', 'ID 3', 'ID 3'],
                   'Code' : ['Apple', 'A123', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'K123', 'K123'],
                   'Code_Type' : ['Code name', 'Code ID', 'Code name', 'Code name', 'Code name', 'Code ID', 'Code ID']}
                 )

df
```

I have a pandas dataframe (~100k rows) that looks something like this.

```
ID      Code    Code_Type
ID 1    Apple   Code name
ID 1    Apple   Code name
ID 1    A123    Code ID
ID 2    Banana  Code name
ID 2    Banana  Code name
ID 3    K123    Code ID
ID 3    K123    Code ID
```

I am trying to iterate through my dataframe and for each ID take the code based on conditions around the code type.

If an ID has both a code name and a code ID associated to it, then take the code ID value and apply it to the code column.

If it has only a code name or a code ID then just pass.

So far the setup I have is something like this.

```
for index, value, value2 in zip(df.ID, df.Code, df.Code_Type):
    print(index, value, value2)
```

However I am not quite sure where to go from here and end up with the resulting dataframe below.

```
ID      Code    Code_Type
ID 1    A123    Code name
ID 1    A123    Code name
ID 1    A123    Code ID
ID 2    Banana  Code name
ID 2    Banana  Code name
ID 3    K123    Code ID
ID 3    K123    Code ID
```

Ideally I would like to create a dictionary mapping like this and just apply that to the dataframe.

```
{'ID 1' : 'A123',
 'ID 2' : 'Banana',
 'ID 3' : 'K123'}
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kenny can you please add your desire output?

Comment: Hi I have added it in the edit, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.query("ID == Code_Type")` this will output only the rows whith the condition you want. Then you can convert it to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here, my logic is to get the last row of each `ID` and then just selecting `Code` column turning it to the dictionary.
Code:

```
df.groupby(['ID']).last()['Code'].T.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'ID 1': 'a123', 'ID 2': 'bANANA', 'ID 3': 'K123'}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.